# Geolocation WatchPosition

Tags: api, html, geolocation, maps

I'm doing a system with Geolocation HTML5 and Google Maps API.
I need the position of the user every second to be refresh (because it's sent through websockets to the central computer) so I've used watchPosition and it doesn't refesh the position every time I would like.

If I refresh the entire web page, it changes sometimes the position so I thought that watchPosition it's not working well.

What I can do?
Use it with setTimeout?

Thanks :)
PD: maximunAge is set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

use the setInterval function in javascript which checks for change in position after every interval of seconds specified.

Comment: At the end, it wasn'y necessary cause watchPosition() returned the position very well in each movement of the device. Thanks :)